# Use of ":" and "of" in the sentences

Tags: prepositions, punctuation

Is use of ":" and "of" in the following sentences correct? If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> They experimentally studied effect of the blade thickness on the
>   turbine performance. They presented two set of rotor blades: the first
>   set of blades was **of** constant thickness with a Naca 0015 profile,
>   along the blade length, while the second set was **of** linearly variable
>   thickness with Naca 0021 at the hub and Naca 0009 at the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll first edit other grammatical inaccuracies. (I didn't know "linearly variable" was a term but it [is](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/10933/4065330/04065344.pdf).) Additionally, you may wish to avoid using "they" to begin two sentences in a row where possible.

> They experimentally studied **the** effect of blade thickness on turbine performance. They presented two set**s** of rotor blades: the first set of blades was of constant thickness with a Naca 0015 profile along the blade length, while the second set was of linearly variable thickness with Naca 0021 at the hub and Naca 0009 at the tip.

The use of colons is bound to draw debate so there is no perfect answer. Some literary styles prefer it because it can be used to read more comfortably, as if a speaker is speaking. Others believe that it should be avoided whenever simpler forms can be found. In any case, your usage is correct in that the colon follows what would otherwise be a complete sentence and adds clarifying information. Your use of "of" is correct in both instances as well. Well done!

That said, even if one can be proud of using complex grammar, this appears to be scientific writing where your primary goal is to make life easier for the reader. One criticism of the colon is that it may force the reader to keep too much in their head at once before the resolution of the sentence. Try:

> They presented two sets of rotor blades. The first set had a consistent thickness with a Naca 0015 profile along the blade length. The other set had a variable thickness with Naca 0021 at the hub and Naca 0009 at the tip.

If I haven't accidentally removed anything important, this may be easier on the audience.